# Remover elemento da lista em C#

Tags: c#, .net, lista

Tenho uma lista e quero que após terminar o `foreach` dessa lista, remova todos os elementos dela, o método `RemoveAll()` pede parâmetro, mas não sei qual parâmetro passar.

```
foreach (var lista in ListaContatos)
{
    lista.Con_codigo = agenciaModel.Bcx_codigo;
    lista.Con_tpcadastro = Con_tpcadastro;
    var stringContent2 = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lista), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(UrlApi2, stringContent2))
    { 
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
ListaContatos.RemoveAll();
```

Comment: Alguma dificuldade em usar o método `Clear()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O método `RemoveAll()` existe para passar uma condição então removerá todos os elementos que cumpra determinada condição, não é para apagar todo de verdade. Ele inclusive é bem ineficiente, mas se é o que precisa é oque tem para usar. Se deseja remover todos elementos mesmo, sem condição alguma o método correto é o `Clear()` que inclusive é tão eficiente quanto possível.

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.clear?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).